# MDB Listener not started

Tags: java, ibm-mq

My current producation MDB running on the AS/400 on version WAS 6.1 .

QA environment is not setup for MDB so I am doing setup,I inserted one message in message queue and setup the MDB to get the message and process the message but MDB Listner not started and giving me error.Same Code working fine prod but it giving me problem in QA

I am using WebSphere Application Server  8.5.5.1  for QA.

[8/27/14 9:47:56:073 EDT] 00000043 MDBListenerIm W   WMSG0019E: Unable to start MDB Listener MDBPortalBean, JMSDestination jms/RECEIVER_QUEUE_CONN_FACTORY_QA : java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSQueueConnectionFactoryHandle incompatible with javax.jms.Destination
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBListenerImpl.createResources(MDBListenerImpl.java:264)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBListenerImpl.internalStart(MDBListenerImpl.java:738)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBListenerImpl.restart(MDBListenerImpl.java:711)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBListenerImpl.alarm(MDBListenerImpl.java:1134)
    at com.ibm.ejs.util.am._Alarm.runImpl(_Alarm.java:151)
    at com.ibm.ejs.util.am._Alarm.run(_Alarm.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)

Comment: Can you check the WebSphere console, and see that your jndi mappings for the EAR file are the same in production as QA? It looks to me like you've mapped a reference to a Queue to a Connection Factory, or vice-versa.

Comment: I didny setup the connection factory ,I setup up Queue connection factories with JNDI jms/RECEIVER_QUEUE_CONN_FACTORY_QA and code is like   QueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory = null;
  JMSLookupFactory jmslookupobj = new JMSLookupFactory(this.m_BusContext, this.m_FtcUsrContxt);

Comment: OK so. Have a look at this: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21385923     It seems to match our problem.

Comment: I change it to jms/RECEIVER_QUEUE_DEST_QA from jms/RECEIVER_QUEUE_CONN_FACTORY_QA which is my JNDI name of Queue and now getting new error WMSG0019E: Unable to start MDB Listener MDBPortalBean, JMSDestination jms/RECEIVER_QUEUE_DEST_QA : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'SENDER_QUEUE_MGR_QA' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'webapp.ftc.org(1416)'. Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.

Comment: maybe you have another QM on this port!!

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you have configured the Listener Port incorrectly. You have set the JMS Destination in the Listener Port configuration to be the QCF when it should be the destination:

`JMSDestination jms/RECEIVER_QUEUE_CONN_FACTORY_QA`

Fix the Listener Port configuration to point to the JMS Destination that you have created and the listener port should start.

Comment: I change it to jms/RECEIVER_QUEUE_DEST_QA and getting this error WMSG0019E: Unable to start MDB Listener MDBPortalBean, JMSDestination jms/RECEIVER_QUEUE_DEST_QA : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'SENDER_QUEUE_MGR_QA' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'webapp.ftc.org(1416)'.
Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.

Comment: As the error suggests there is a problem connecting to that queue manager using those connection settings. Check that SENDER_QUEUE_MGR_QA is the right queue manager name and that the host/port are correct for that queue manager.